# consistany of device.uuid in phonegap android

Tags: android, cordova, uuid

I am using phonegap for my Hybrid Moble app.The user will have a user name and password to enter into this app.A particular user can use only one device to login to this app.For this i am using the device.uuid for getting the user device unuquily and based on that,that particular user is only allowed to login from that particular device.Now i have three doubts.

- Will the device.uuid changes on changing the sim card?
- Will the device.uuid changes on re booting the device?
- Will the device.uuid changes on changing the wifi network?
- Will the device.uuid changes on Upgrading or changing the OS version(Android)?
  -And how consistend it is?

Thanks a  lot

Answer (score 1):

UUID stands for **U**niversally **U**nique **Id**entifier.

> - Will the device.uuid changes on changing the sim card?
> - Will the device.uuid changes on re booting the device?
> - Will the device.uuid changes on changing the wifi network?
> - Will the device.uuid changes on Upgrading or changing the OS    version(Android)? And how consistent it is?

Answer is No, for all the questions; the UUID will not change unless the user can fake it, which is not easy. There is a very rare possibility of the UUID conflict between 2 users, [check this link to know more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates).

Thanks to jcesarmobile for pointing that out, factory resets may change the device's UUID.

Comment: just want to add that the uuid may change if a factory reset is performed on the device.

Comment: it changes yes, even when you update the OS. not to mention it is even less reliable on iOS.